# rostest: specifying a single test case

Tags: rostest, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I tell rostest to only run a single specific test method in a python unittest.TestCase class?
I can execute the full test suite with:

```
rostest foo foo.test
```

The tests are defined in a file test/rostest_foo.py, how do I run only the test method test_a in class TestFoo?
Any command line arguments to rostest?

My test classes are looking like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import unittest

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_a(self):
        self.assertEqual(2+3, 5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import rostest
    rospy.init_node('TestFoo', anonymous=True)
    rostest.rosrun('foo', 'TestFoo', TestFoo)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285155/rostest:-specifying-a-single-test-case/) by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 811 on 2018-03-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answering my own old question:

in ROS melodic you can use a string describing a specific test like this:

```
rostest.rosrun('foo', 'TestFoo', '__main__.TestFoo.test_a')
```

... and of course that string may come from command line arguments.

---

Originally posted by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) with karma: 811 on 2022-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0